# How to make radio "checkbox" look like a real button with ASP?

Tags: asp.net, radio-button

I'm new to ASP programming and web development.

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap 3 on a new project.

Using the above html code:

```
                    <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" data-toggle="buttons">
                        <label class="btn btn-default active">
                            <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1">
                            <i class="fa fa-user"></i>.Para mim
                        </label>
                        <label class="btn btn-default">
                            <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" onclick="paraEmpresa()">
                            <i class="fa fa-briefcase"></i>.Para minha empresa
                        </label>
                    </div>
```

I got a two buttons to work like radio, like these:

[image]

The question is: **how can I make the same using ASP.net elements?**

Note: I don't know the terms to do the proper search. RADIO BUTTONS are rounded, but I can't figure how radio button REAL buttons are called. Appreciate the help.

Comment: As long as your `<input type="radio" />` controls are wrapped inside a `<form>` that uses `GET` or `POST` to send data to an asp page, you should be able to display the value in your asp page using either `Request.QueryString("options")` for a `GET` or `Request.Form("options")` for a `POST`.

Comment: I think thats not what I need. It is useful information thought. TY

Comment: I don't think this is a Classic ASP question.  Bootstrap is a client side library which shouldn't interfere with your server side code.  Are you asking how you can use Bootstrap in conjunction with the `<asp:Radiobuttonlist>` control?  If you are then you need to tag this question as asp.net rather than classic asp

Comment: I jumped right into programming, I have some misconception between ASP and ASP.net. I'll read more about it and edit the question. Thank you.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  You can use the code you posted in asp.net, and pull the data as @Lankymart suggested. If you need to set the data, you can add the `runat="server"` property to the radiobuttons and access them server-side.

Comment: Good spot @John, will leave it at that.

Comment: Portuguese. Nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you need

```
              <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" data-toggle="buttons">
                    <label class="btn btn-default active">
                        <asp:RadioButton id="option1" runat="server" GroupName="options"></asp:RadioButton>
                        <i class="fa fa-user"></i>.Para mim
                    </label>
                    <label class="btn btn-default">
                        <asp:RadioButton id="option2" runat="server" GroupName="options" ></asp:RadioButton>
                        <i class="fa fa-briefcase"></i>.Para minha empresa
                    </label>
                </div>
```